# Why is the cache sometimes reset?

Tags: cmake

For example, when I change the compiler, the whole cache is deleted and needs to be reconfigured. I understand that things like the compiler flags would need to be reset but why the whole cache?

Comment: Are you sure that the whole cache is deleted? Reconfigurations may happen even if cache stays.

Comment: Do we talk about the following warning: `You have changed variables that require your cache to be deleted. Configure will be re-run and you may have to reset some variables. The following variables have changed: ...`?

Comment: @Florian Yes, that one. When that happens, I have to reset everything, even variables that aren't related to the compiler in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer*

**The Message itself**

The CMake message

> *"You have changed variables that require your cache to be deleted. Configure will be re-run and you may have to reset some variables. The following variables have changed: ...*"

translates to something like

> *"CMake tries to behave and is not telling you that for a change like that you have to delete your binary output directory and start from scratch again."*

This feature came a long time ago with ["ENH: fix for bug 6102, allow users to change the compiler" commit](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/commit/fd33bf93a5e9d86ee249cc3fde22a221dfe861e8) and was improved with ["Delete entire CMakeFiles directory when deleting CMakeCache.txt" commit](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/commit/1df09e57732501454ac2bee900d2aad963a84969):

> Fix this simply by teaching cmCacheManager::DeleteCache to remove the
>   entire CMakeFiles directory recursively whenever it removes an existing
>   CMakeCache.txt.  This fully resets the build tree to configure with a
>   fresh compiler.

**Why does it have to delete everything?**

If you change the compiler or upgrade to a newer version of CMake, your generated build environment could not just simply be adapted.

All cached configurations - as being an evaluation or search results based on the compiler and platform information - have to be deleted and re-run. CMake could simply not know which cached variable is still valid in the new environment.

Comment: So basically, it would be too difficult to track which variables are affected by the compiler change and which are not. That's what I suspected. Thanks!